# Batch probblem: Cant iterate through string variable

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, token, batch-processing

I'm going crazy for 2 days with this simple task: iterate through a 5 line string with delimiters (or a file with the same content). After I find a delimiter symbol I expect to write that line to the file, then add echo for a cr/lf representation and do next iteration for a next piece of string.

For academic purposes I recreate the code like that:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set "LF=&echo."
set "dlm=+"
set "s1=A A A" 
set "s2=B B B" 
set "s3=C C C" 
set "s4=D D D" 
set "s5=E E E" 

set "s=%s1%%dlm%%s2%%dlm%%s3%%dlm%%s4%%dlm%%s5%%dlm%"

for /f "tokens=* delims=+" %%i in ("%s%") do (
    echo %%i>>test.txt
    echo. >>test.txt
)
pause
```

The output is like:

```
A A A+B B B+C C C+D D D+E E E+
newline
```

When I want this

```
A A A
B B B
C C C
D D D
E E E
```

When I change token to 1 or 2 it returns the correct line

How to get those sub strings and write them to the file? Why tokens don't work?

I tried to put this into another loop and pass token number as !j!, but it doesn't work. I also thought of a few goto but think it's a bad practice.

Comment: I run this on win7 if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subroutine `split_supplied_line` in the following batch code snippet should do the trick for (*almost*) any number of substrings and (*almost*) any delimiter. No matter whether there is a trailing delimiter.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LF=&echo."
set "dlm=+"
set "s1=A A A" 
set "s2=B B B" 
set "s3=C C C" 
set "s4=D D D" 
set "s5=E E E" 
set "s=%s1%%dlm%%s2%%dlm%%s3%%dlm%%s4%%dlm%%s5%%dlm%"
rem set "s=%s1%%dlm%%s2%%dlm%%s3%%dlm%%s4%%dlm%%s5%" without trailing %dlm%

call :split_supplied_line "%s%" "%dlm%" "72351984test.txt"
goto :eof

:split_supplied_line
set "restofline=%~1" 1st parameter: line to split
set "delims=%~2"     2nd parameter: delimiter character
set "tofile=%~3"     3rd parameter: file where to write
:in_split_supplied_line
call set "noplusline=%restofline:%delims%=%"
if "%noplusline%"=="%restofline%" (
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo !restofline!>>"%tofile%"
  ENDLOCAL
  goto :eof
)
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=%delims%" %%i in ("%restofline%") do (
    echo %%i>>"%tofile%""
    set "restofline=%%j"
)
if ""=="%restofline%" goto :eof
goto :in_split_supplied_line
```

**Output**: `2>nul del 72351984test.txt & .\SO\72351984.bat & type 72351984test.txt`

```
A A A
B B B
C C C
D D D
E E E
```

However, there is a more tricky approach (unfortunately, a trailing delimiter adds a blank line into the output):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LF=&echo."
set "dlm=+"
set "s1=A A A" 
set "s2=B B B" 
set "s3=C C C" 
set "s4=D D D" 
set "s5=E E E" 
set "s=%s1%%dlm%%s2%%dlm%%s3%%dlm%%s4%%dlm%%s5%%dlm%"
rem set "s=%s1%%dlm%%s2%%dlm%%s3%%dlm%%s4%%dlm%%s5%" without trailing %dlm%

>72351984test.txt (echo %s:+=&echo.%)

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

**Output**: `2>nul del 72351984test.txt & .\SO\72351984a.bat & type 72351984test.txt`

```
A A A
B B B
C C C
D D D
E E E
```

Answer (score 1):

With "Tokens=*" you request the for-loop to return everything it finds into the first parameter, and in doing so completely ignore the delims-clause.

What you want is the first 5 tokens, separated by delimiter "+".

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=+" %%i in ("%s%") do  >>test.txt (
echo %%i
echo %%j
echo %%k
echo %%l
echo %%m
echo.
```

)

Comment: Thanks so much! And what if I have 99 substrings? How to iterate through big amount of substrings, separated by special delimiter?

Comment: `With "Tokens=*" you request the for-loop to return everything it finds into the first parameter, and in doing so completely ignore the delims-clause.` Um, not the case. `tokens=*` strips any leading delimiters from the line, including the default delimiters if no `delims` are defined. `delims=` on the other hand delivers the entire line.